# Event ESENT 508 on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

My monitoring system informed me about the following event log entry on my Azure VM (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter):

> Catalog Database (1180) Catalog Database: A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot2{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\catdb" at offset 48676864 (0x0000000002e6c000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes succeeded, but took an abnormally long time (17 seconds) to be serviced by the OS. This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.
>
> (EventLog: Application, Source: ESENT, EventID: 508, EventLevelName: Warning)

I remember seeing this message before, a few months ago (and maybe another time a few months before that). The machine is an Azure VM, so my "hardware vendor" is Microsoft.

So, is the event log warning (a) likely to point to a serious problem that needs addressing, or (b) a well-known false positive in hosting scenarios?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman: Thanks for the edit!